# MobileSync POST requests timing out

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

The POST Requests from Salesforce MobileSync SDK are timing out but the same GET Requests are not. Also, The request with same parameters works via Postman(Its an application used for API Testing).

What we've tried so far:

- Upgrading/Downgrading SDK.
- Testing on multiple devices.
- Using URLSession to call the same API. Which doesn't timeout but throws 400.
- Debugging into the SDK Classes. The flow for GET and POST Requests are same.

I'm also providing an example of how we are creating request and calling them.

```
func salesforceRequest(path: BNFSalesForceEndPoint, method: RestRequest.Method) -> RestRequest? {
         
         guard let token = UserAccountManager.shared.currentUserAccount?.credentials.accessToken else {
             print("Error getting token from: \(UserAccountManager.shared.currentUserAccount.debugDescription)")
             return  nil
         }
         
         var queryParams: [String: Any]?
         #if DEBUG
         queryParams = ["debugMode": "true"]
         #endif
 
        let request = RestRequest.customUrlRequest(with: method, baseURL: BNFSalesForceEndPoint.base.rawValue, path: path.rawValue, queryParams: queryParams)
 
        request.setHeaderValue("Bearer \(token)", forHeaderName: "Authorization")
 
        return request
    }
 
func salesforceSendRequest<T: Encodable>(with request: RestRequest, and bodyData: T, completion: @escaping (BNFSalesforceResult<Int, String>) -> Void) {
 
        do {
 
            let data = try JSONEncoder.init().encode(bodyData)
            request.setCustomRequestBodyString(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!, contentType: "application/json")
 
            RestClient.sharedGlobal.send(request: request) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):
                    guard let urlResponse = response.urlResponse as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                        completion(.failure("Unknown response: \(response)"))
                        return
                    }
                    guard urlResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                        completion(.failure("HTTP Code: \(urlResponse.statusCode)"))
                        return
                    }
                    completion(.success(urlResponse.statusCode))
                case .failure(let error):
                    BNFSalesforceAuthManager.handleNetworkError(error)
                    completion(.failure("network error: \(error.localizedDescription)"))
                }
            }
 
        } catch {
            print("SalesforceSDK Error encoding data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(.failure(error.localizedDescription))
        }
    }
```

XCode: 13.2.1

MobileSync SDK: 9.2.1

Minimum iOS Version: 13.0